# Future Builder loading time: is adding a delay a good practice?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Assume we have the following `FutureBuilder`:

```dart
 return FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
      future: users.doc(documentId).get(),
      builder:
          (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {

        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Text("Something went wrong");
        }

        if (snapshot.hasData && !snapshot.data!.exists) {
          return Text("Document does not exist");
        }

        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          Map<String, dynamic> data = snapshot.data!.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
          return Text("Full Name: ${data['full_name']} ${data['last_name']}");
        }

        return CircularProgressIndicator();
      },
    );
```

Flutter will show `CircularProgressIndicator` while fetching data from Firestore. However, it is pretty fast so the `CircularProgressIndicator` will be shown for few milliseconds, resulting in a glitchy UX. How do you handle these situations?
Do you add a standard minimum delay (e.g. 1 seconds) to the future?

Comment: https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/animation/opacity-animation - you can fade in your circular progress indicator so that it doesn't flicker

Comment: I don't know if this solves the problem. How is it supposed to know when to start fading?

Comment: To add on to the answer by @pskink, here's how you can modify it to know when to start fading
```
return AnimatedOpacity(
      opacity: snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting ? 1.0 : 0.0,
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
      child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
    );
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the issue about the duration of the CircularProgressindicator. Won't it still result glitchy, if we don't change his duration?

Comment: `class FooAnimatedOpacity extends StatelessWidget {
const FooAnimatedOpacity({required this.child, this.duration = const Duration(milliseconds: 500)});

final Widget child;
final Duration duration;

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return FutureBuilder(
future: Future.value(1),
builder: (ctx, s) => AnimatedOpacity(
opacity: s.hasData? 1 : 0,
duration: duration,
child: child,
)
);
}
}` and instead `return CircularProgressIndicator();` use `return FooAnimatedOpacity(child: CircularProgressIndicator());`

Comment: and you can further customize how it fades in by adding `curve` parameter to `AnimatedOpacity`